# Merging two for loops together under an if statement

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, split, strip

I am trying to merge these two codes together so that the final piece can append the text document "Payments" into a list. For each line of "Payments", I want it within a list in `myList`, so it would look something like this:

```
myList = [['E1234','12/09/14','440','A','0']['E3431','10/01/12','320','N','120']['E0987','04/12/16','342','A','137']]
```

I want to be able to create the final code to prompt the user to enter a customer number, then search through `myList` for the customer number and display all the information for the customer on the screen.

This is the first of the two programs. It is the "backbone" of the final code. Let's call this A:

```
print("Option A: Show a record\nOption Q: Quit")
decision = input("Enter A or Q: ")

if decision == "A" or decision == "a":
    myFile = open("Payments.txt")
    customer_number = input("Enter a customer number to view their details: ")
    record = myFile.readlines()
    for line in record:
        if customer_number in line:
            print(line)
    myFile.close()

elif decision == "Q" or "q":
    exit
```

This is the second piece of code. Let's call this B:

```
myFile = open("Payments.txt")
myList = []
for item in myFile:
    print(item.strip())
    myList.append(item.strip().split(','))
myFile.close()
print(myList)
```

I want to insert B into the if statement: `if decision == "A" or decision == "a":`.

I am confused about the for loops as there is a for loop in A and B, both which are vital for the final code. I am unable to place B into A without disrupting either one of the for loops.

```
print("Option A: Show a record\nOption Q: Quit")
decision = input("Enter A or Q: ")
myList = []

if decision == "A" or decision == "a":
    myFile = open("Payments.txt")
    customer_number = input("Enter a customer number to view their details: ")
    record = myFile.readlines()
    for line in record:
        for item in myFile:
            print(item.strip())
            myList.append(item.strip().split(','))
            print(myList)
        if customer_number in line:
            print(line)
    myFile.close()

elif decision == "Q" or "q":
    exit
```

It displays the line from which the customer number is from, but it doesn't print the list.

**Update**

I want to be able to print the individual data from each line separately:

```
Customer number: E1234
Date of payment: 12/09/14
Payment amount: £440
Paid amount: £0
```

Comment: If I understand correctly A just prints out the specific customer's details but what does B do? Just print out contents of Payments.txt?

Comment: B adds each line of Payments.txt to an individual list inside myList. I want B inside the if statement in A so it will append Payments to myList, find the customer_number in the list and display that particular line

Comment: So the whole purpose of this is to display the line that contains customer_number? Why even bother with `myList`?

Comment: It is required by the rules to use a list in this code for this job. Sorry that I haven't explained that previously.

Comment: Okay I modified my solution to fix this and do what you want :) You were on right track but you were not printing the right values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment you mentioned you *need* to append to a list so I have modified my script to include that but your current answer was separating your A and B part but you had to combine them.

The logic is, if customer_number exists in a line, then you append to list and use a loop to iterate through the list to print what you want. Your solution was printing the entire line of the customers details and also printing every other line.

```
print("Option A: Show a record\nOption Q: Quit")
decision = input("Enter A or Q: ").lower()
myList = []

if decision == "a":
    myFile = open("Payments.txt")
    customer_number = input("Enter a customer number to view their details: ")
    record = myFile.readlines()
    for line in record:
        if customer_number in line:
            myList.append(line.strip().replace("'","").split(','))
            for info in myList:
                print("Customer number: ", info[0])
                print("Date of payment: ", info[1])
                print("Payment Amount: ", info[2])
                print("Paid Amount: ", info[4])
    myFile.close()

elif decision == "q":
    exit()
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Why do you loop over the content of the file twice?

Comment: It didn't work. It printed each individual line, then showed that it was appending it to `myList`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to create the final code to prompt the user to enter
>   a customer number, then search through myList for the customer number
>   and display all the information for the customer on the screen.

I made a few modifications to your code, and put in PEP-8 compliant Boilerplate.

```
def customer_payment(customer_number):
    """Edited Code. Purpose is to accept User Input for a customer number
    Search for Customer Number, and if Found, Display Information about Customer.
    """
    myList = []
    with open("Payments.txt") as myFile:  
        for line in myFile:
            if customer_number in line:
                print(line)
            for item in line:
                print(item.strip())
                myList.append(line.strip().split(','))


def main():
    decision = input("Option A: Show a record\nOption Q: Quit\nEnter A or Q: ")
    if decision.lower() == "a":
        customer_number = input("Enter a customer number to view their details: ")
        customer_payment(customer_number)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

This may need to be modified based upon the format that Payments.txt is in.